# Razor Reusable Form View With Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, data-annotations

We're using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Razor to render many Twitter Bootstrap html forms, each with it's own model. Data Annotations are used for server and client side validation.

We have tried to create a generic, reusable partial view / component / tag helper / etc to render the same html for all fields, but found none of the method working.

Consider the following fields with data annotations:

```cs
[BindProperty, Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is required"), RegularExpression("[^\\s]+", ErrorMessage = "No spaces allowed")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[BindProperty, Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is required")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
[BindProperty] [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid e-mailaddress")]
public string Emailaddress { get; set; }
```

Each field should render the following html:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" asp-for="FirstName/LastName/Emailaddress">
        Your first name / last name / e-mailaddress
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input asp-for="FirstName/LastName/Emailaddress" class="form-control input-md" />
        <span class="invalid-feedback" asp-validation-for="FirstName/LastName/Emailaddress"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to be able to create a simple Razor page, such as (or any other method):

```html
<form method="Post">
   <partial name="partialFormTextInput for="FirstName" />
   <partial name="partialFormTextInput for="LastName" />
   <partial name="partialFormTextInput for="Emailaddress" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

It would greatly simplify the process of creating forms for different models. We have found that the primary issue is in the data annotations, as they do not render in partial views, nor in tag helpers.

Has anyone succeeded in creating this?

**Update**
If a partial view is used, the actual (simplified) result is:

```html
<input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" value="">
<span class="invalid-feedback field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

While the expected result is:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control input-md" data-val="true" data-val-regex="No spaces allowed" data-val-regex-pattern="[^\s]+" data-val-required="Field is required" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" value="">
<span class="invalid-feedback field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

The data-val* attributes are missing on the input

Comment: Hi @Astronout, I could render the data annotations successfully in my project. What is your result? Could you please share a screenshot to us?

Comment: Besides, did you add `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
` in _ViewImports.cshtml?

Comment: Hi @Rena, thanks for your reply. In your case, does it render with the data annotation validations in the input tag? That what's missing in my case. I expect this `<input type="text" class="form-control input-md" data-val="true" data-val-regex="No spaces allowed" data-val-regex-pattern="[^\s]+" data-val-required="Field is required" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" value="">` but the data-val-* attributes are missing